# QT Jambi HTML5 Video

Tags: qt, video, html, qt-jambi

Is it possible to use the HTML5 `<video>` element within a QT Jambi QWebView? I have set up a basic app, but it doesn't display `<video>` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No.

QT HTML5 video tag support is still [under development](http://qt.nokia.com/products/library/qtwebkit/) as of March 2011.  And my bet is that it never will, as that Nokia has lost interest in Symbian.